# C++ ios:fail() flag

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to read a las file larger then 2GBs (about 15GBs) but ios::fail() flag becomes true in 345th byte. Here is the code below.

```
void Foo()
{
  char* filename = "../../../../../CAD/emi/LAS_Data/AOI.las";
  ifstream m_file (filename);

  char c;
  int count = 0;

  if (m_file.is_open())
  {
      while ( m_file.good() )
      {
          m_file.get(c);
          cout << c << endl;
          count++;
      }

      // Check State

      if(m_file.fail())
          cout << "File Error: logical error in i/o operation." << endl;

      if(m_file.eof())
          cout << "Total Bytes Read: " << count << endl;

      m_file.close();
  }
  else
  {
      cout << "File Error: Couldn't open file: " << endl;
  }
}
```

And the output is:

```
...
File Error: logical error in i/o operation.
Total Bytes Read: 345
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `while (m_file.good())` is wrong. Which resource told you to do that? Also LOL 15GB.

Comment: For a 15GB file I would better use memorry mapped files.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/
I tried 'while(!m_file.eof())' but nothing changed. Is it about the size of file? But is it not early for seeing the error(345th byte)?

I am going to search for memory mapped files as soon as possible.

Comment: The tutorial there sucks hard in too many aspects. The point why your loop is wrong is that you will only get the failure bit *after* an operation failed. Therefore, you have to read a character and then check for success before using what you read (or perhaps failed to read). BTW: Make that a `char const* filename = ...`.

Comment: Reading a 15GB file with `get` is really not a very good idea. It will be very slow.

Comment: OK. I am going to use liblas... Of course didn't think to use getc to read whole file, trying to understand the header...

Comment: According to this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/ fail() might be set on a bad bit which is not a logical error. Be mindful of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're using Windows. Windows has a quirk that a Control-Z marks the end of a text file, no matter how large the file actually is. The solution is to open the file in Binary mode.

```
ifstream m_file (filename, std::ios::binary);
```